# Sed with space in python

Tags: python, sed, vcenter

I was trying perform replace using sed in `VMkernel`. I used the following command,

```
sed s/myname/sample name/g txt.txt
```

I got an error saying `sed: unmatched '/'`.
I replaced space with `\`. It worked.

When I tried the same using python,

```
def executeCommand(cmd):
   process = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   output, error = process.communicate()
   print (output.decode("utf-8")) 
executeCommand('sed s/myname/sample\ name/g txt.txt')
```

I am getting the error `sed: unmatched '/'` again. I used `\s` instead of space I am getting the name replaced with `samplesname`.

How can I replace a string with space?

Comment: split() by default splits by space... so of course you'll have issues... with `\s` python string acts up... use `r'string'` format instead

Comment: Quoting.  In the shell:  `sed 's/myname/sample name/g' txt.txt`  In python:  `executeCommand('sed s/myname/sample\\ name/g txt.txt')` (extra backslash) - untested.

Comment: By using `split()` you are sending the list `['sed', 's/myname/sample\', 'name/g', 'txt.txt']` to subprocess. The sed expression is split in half. It's better to create the list yourself, so you have full control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to not be smart about splitting the command:

```
executeCommand(['sed', 's/myname/sample name/g', 'txt.txt'])
```

Otherwise you are opening a can of worms, effectively playing a shell parser role.

---

Alternatively you may run the command in a shell and let the shell parse and run the command:

```
import subprocess

def executeCommand(cmd):
   process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   # Or:
   # This will run the command in /bin/bash (instead of /bin/sh)
   process = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   output, error = process.communicate()
   print (output.decode("utf-8")) 

executeCommand("sed 's/myname/sample name/g' txt.txt")
```